# GitHub Pages: Octopress in Subfolder (other pages in root)

Tags: jekyll, octopress, github-pages

I'm in the process of moving my blog from self-hosted [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) to ([GitHub-pages powered](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/)) [Octopress](http://octopress.org).

Thus far, I have successfully set up & copied my blog over to `myusername.github.com`, which has the `CNAME` `http://mydomain.com`. (So, browsing `http://mydomain.com` shows my Octopress blog. Dandy.)

I would like to modify my setup so that things are as follows:

- `http://mydomain.com` → Simple html landing page
- `http://mydomain.com/blog` → Octopress blog, in all its glory
- `http://mydomain.com/sdf` → Miscelaneous other simple html sites that I would like to host
- `http://mydomain.com/sdfsdfdsf` -> As above
- ... (an arbitrary number of other root-level sites)

However…I would like my landing page (and other misc sites) to be hosted from the GitHub-pages repo, and the source stored alongside Octopress.

Ideally, `«octopress»/source/` would look like this:

- `«octopress»/source/index.html` → My landing page
- `«octopress»/source/blog/*` → Normal Octopress source folder (contains `_posts`, `assets`, `_layouts`, etc.)
- `«octopress»/source/sdf/index.html` → Other misc sites

Thus far, I have found instructions about [how to deploy Octopress to a subdirectory](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/subdir/). But as far as I can tell, these instructions don't allow you to have other misc sites under `«octopress»/source/`.

I would love suggestions about how to accomplish what I'm after.  I have a feeling it won't be hard (just tweaks to some Jekyll files somewhere, perhaps).

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Jekyll locally rather than using the version on the github server, you don't need to do everything within Jekyll - simply have a shell script move some folders around between the generate and deploy steps.

After Jekyll runs, everything is static files, and the deployment step is just committing and pushing whatever happens to be in the output folder at that point.

Comment: Good point - I could do the deploy step manually with a shell script. It would be great if there was a way to have Jekyll do this for me though (I guess I could add a task to the Rakefile to make this a bit more seamless?)

Answer (score 3):

You can change your blog index page to `blog/index.html` like [the document describes](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/template/#landing_page). Then, put your landing page and other sites into `/source` directory.